# ECLIPSE html not displaying

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp

I have the following servlet:

```
package gui;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HelloWorld
 */
@WebServlet("/HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public HelloWorld() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<b> Hello World! </b>");
    out.println("</html>");



}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

When I run this on server I get:

Served at: /HelloWorld html

b  Hello World! /b

/html

with <> around html, b, /b, /html  instead of the actual html.  When I inspect element I notice there is no !DOCTYPE html tag

Comment: The output is consistent with the program. There is no doctype because you don't send one. Normally your servlet should call a JSP to do all the presentation work.

Comment: You print text, then the html tags. Put everything in the html tags and see what happens.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just needed to comment out the following line:

```
response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
```

Answer (score -1):

A servlet has no idea hat a web page is, it even hasn't any idea about the type of data you are sending. It's just a mechanism to send a stream of bytes to the client (in fact, you can write servlets that serve up gifs, jpg's, word documents and so on - just set the proper `response.setContentType` and emit the data in the proper format). That makes it super flexible, but it also means that you have to do everything yourself. And, as in your code, everything you don't explicitly send won't be sent (like the missing doctype), and what you send at the wrong moment will end up in the page at the wrong place (like `response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());` that gets sent before the start of the page.

A valid servlet doGet method that sends out a basic webpage almost identical to your code could look like this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // announce that we're going to send html in the UTF-8 charset
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    // grab the response's Writer and use that to output data
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        // send the doctype
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        // send the page
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>My servlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Served at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
        out.println("<b>Hello World!</b>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

As you can see this gets impractical really quickly. That's why typically servlets rely on a presentation technology like JSP to perform the presentation.